# Session Management For Multiple Server

Tags: asp.net, iis, session-management, web-farm, web-garden

I want to move data with session using asp.net . I want to explain my question with scenario.

I have four layers in my application. When I login my portal with user password I create session for username and userid. for example,I have three servers for business layer that has load balance in front of each server.
How can i carry data(username/userid session) with this scenario. Or if you have a different way for carry data (without session) can you share ?(I added a picture for my scenario.) [image]

Note: I am only a software developer and I want to search best practice for this scenario.

Comment: Store Session in shared DB...

Comment: you can store the session state in a database shared by all the servers. This can be setup in your web.config. Plenty of info on google.

Comment: Tens of thousands of users can login with same time. 
They can start thousands of transactions in minutes.
I need this session(userid/username) before every process.is it reasonable in this case?

Comment: If your SQL hardware is good enough then it shouldn't be too bad. There's no other sensible way really. If you don't share the session state between the servers then the users' session will break if the load balancer directs them to a different businesslayer server on the next request. It's necessary for your application to function sanely, never mind to fulfil your specific scenario.